# ProGuard is getting rid of some required code?

Tags: proguard, android-proguard

Hi I need some help with writing my proguard-rules.pro file. I have very limited knowledge on this and have written the following so far with the help of the internet.

```
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in C:\Users\Suresh Babu\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the proguardFiles
# directive in build.gradle.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#
#}
-dontpreverify
-repackageclasses ''
-allowaccessmodification
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-dontwarn android.support.**
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontshrink
-dontoptimize

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public abstract class *
-keep public interface *
-keep public abstract class edu.cias.rit.rocreadar.AbstractArchitectCamActivity
-keep public class edu.cias.rit.rocreadar.MainActivity

-keep public class * extends android.annotation.SuppressLint
-keep public class * extends android.content.ComponentCallbacks2
-keep public class * extends android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo
-keep public class * extends android.location.Location
-keep public class * extends android.location.LocationListener
-keep public class * extends android.media.AudioManager
-keep public class * extends android.opengl.GLES20
-keep public class * extends android.os.Build
-keep public class * extends android.os.Bundle
-keep public class * extends android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
-keep public class * extends android.util.Log
-keep public class * extends android.webkit.WebView
-keep public class * extends android.widget.Toast

-keep public class * extends com.wikitude.architect.ArchitectView
-keep public class * extends com.wikitude.architect.ArchitectView.ArchitectUrlListener
-keep public class * extends com.wikitude.architect.ArchitectView.SensorAccuracyChangeListener
-keep public class * extends com.wikitude.architect.StartupConfiguration
-keep public class * extends com.wikitude.architect.StartupConfiguration.CameraPosition

-keep public class * extends org.json.JSONArray
-keep public class * extends org.json.JSONObject

-keep public class * extends java.io.IOException
-keep public class * extends java.util.HashMap


-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
    public void set*(...);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.content.Context {
   public void *(android.view.View);
   public void *(android.view.MenuItem);
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    static ** CREATOR;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

-keepclassmembers class * {
    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    *** *Callback(...);
}

-keep class edu.cias.rit.AbstractArchitectCamActivity {
    void onCreate(***);
}
```

Following is the stacktrace. When I start my app, it crashes. It is supposed to open a splashscreen and the main activity etc.

```
11-23 16:32:06.244     792-1266/? I/ActivityManager﹕ START u0 {act=android.intent.action.DELETE dat=package:edu.cias.rit.rocreadar flg=0x10800000 cmp=com.android.packageinstaller/.UninstallerActivity (has extras)} from uid 10022 on display 0
11-23 16:32:07.296      792-805/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Force stopping edu.cias.rit.rocreadar appid=10227 user=-1: uninstall pkg
11-23 16:32:07.646      792-823/? W/PackageManager﹕ Couldn't remove dex file for package:  at location /data/app/edu.cias.rit.rocreadar-1/base.apk, retcode=-1
11-23 16:32:07.748      792-823/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Force stopping edu.cias.rit.rocreadar appid=10227 user=0: pkg removed
11-23 16:32:07.866   3838-31907/? D/VoicemailCleanupService﹕ Cleaning up data for package: edu.cias.rit.rocreadar
11-23 16:32:08.018   1985-31925/? D/PackageBroadcastService﹕ Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED and uri=edu.cias.rit.rocreadar
11-23 16:32:08.018   1985-31925/? D/AccountUtils﹕ Clearing selected account for edu.cias.rit.rocreadar
11-23 16:32:08.029   1985-31925/? I/LocationSettingsChecker﹕ Removing dialog suppression flag for package edu.cias.rit.rocreadar
11-23 16:32:08.066   1985-31929/? D/gH_MetricsDatabase﹕ 0 metrics were deleted when clearing package edu.cias.rit.rocreadar.
11-23 16:32:08.073    1985-2711/? I/Icing﹕ doRemovePackageData edu.cias.rit.rocreadar
11-23 16:32:08.114   1667-31938/? I/UpdateIcingCorporaServi﹕ Updating corpora: APPS=edu.cias.rit.rocreadar, CONTACTS=MAYBE
11-23 16:32:19.291      792-823/? I/PackageManager.DexOptimizer﹕ Running dexopt (dex2oat) on: /data/app/vmdl413714101.tmp/base.apk pkg=edu.cias.rit.rocreadar isa=arm vmSafeMode=false debuggable=false oatDir = /data/app/vmdl413714101.tmp/oat
11-23 16:32:23.933      792-823/? W/PackageManager﹕ Unknown permission android.permission.ACCESS_GPS in package edu.cias.rit.rocreadar
11-23 16:32:24.070      792-823/? V/BackupManagerService﹕ restoreAtInstall pkg=edu.cias.rit.rocreadar token=e restoreSet=0
11-23 16:32:24.331   1985-32123/? D/PackageBroadcastService﹕ Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED and uri=edu.cias.rit.rocreadar
11-23 16:32:24.349   1985-32126/? D/h﹕ Processing package: edu.cias.rit.rocreadar
11-23 16:32:24.380   1985-32126/? D/GassUtils﹕ Found app info for package edu.cias.rit.rocreadar:4. Hash: fb4fd99240fc2e2facc7748090f26288d88d4ddb3bd70b25bcf2d6cfc040f92a
11-23 16:32:24.380   1985-32126/? D/h﹕ Found info for package edu.cias.rit.rocreadar in db.
11-23 16:32:24.457   1667-32132/? I/UpdateIcingCorporaServi﹕ Updating corpora: APPS=edu.cias.rit.rocreadar, CONTACTS=MAYBE
11-23 16:32:26.100     792-1699/? I/ActivityManager﹕ START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 pkg=edu.cias.rit.rocreadar cmp=edu.cias.rit.rocreadar/.SplashScreen} from uid 10063 on display 0
11-23 16:32:26.153    792-13663/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Start proc 32141:edu.cias.rit.rocreadar/u0a228 for activity edu.cias.rit.rocreadar/.SplashScreen
11-23 16:32:26.479      792-810/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Displayed edu.cias.rit.rocreadar/.SplashScreen: +343ms
11-23 16:32:28.282    792-24283/? I/ActivityManager﹕ START u0 {cmp=edu.cias.rit.rocreadar/.MainActivity} from uid 10228 on display 0
11-23 16:32:28.486  32141-32141/? A/art﹕ art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #05 pc 0025237b  /data/app/edu.cias.rit.rocreadar-1/lib/arm/libarchitect.so (Java_com_wikitude_architect_Gameplay_createNative+74)
11-23 16:32:28.486  32141-32141/? A/art﹕ art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #06 pc 002c742f  /data/app/edu.cias.rit.rocreadar-1/oat/arm/base.odex (Java_com_wikitude_architect_Gameplay_createNative__+74)
11-23 16:32:28.487  32141-32141/? A/art﹕ art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at edu.cias.rit.rocreadar.AbstractArchitectCamActivity.onCreate(unavailable:-1)
11-23 16:32:28.487  32141-32141/? A/art﹕ art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at edu.cias.rit.rocreadar.MainActivity.onCreate(unavailable:-1)
11-23 16:32:28.614  32141-32141/? A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   native: #08 pc 0025237b  /data/app/edu.cias.rit.rocreadar-1/lib/arm/libarchitect.so (Java_com_wikitude_architect_Gameplay_createNative+74)
11-23 16:32:28.614  32141-32141/? A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   native: #09 pc 002c742f  /data/app/edu.cias.rit.rocreadar-1/oat/arm/base.odex (???)
11-23 16:32:28.614  32141-32141/? A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   at edu.cias.rit.rocreadar.AbstractArchitectCamActivity.onCreate(unavailable:-1)
11-23 16:32:28.614  32141-32141/? A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   at edu.cias.rit.rocreadar.MainActivity.onCreate(unavailable:-1)
11-23 16:32:28.614  32141-32141/? A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   at void edu.cias.rit.rocreadar.AbstractArchitectCamActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) ((null):-1)
11-23 16:32:28.614  32141-32141/? A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   at void edu.cias.rit.rocreadar.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) ((null):-1)
11-23 16:32:28.615  32141-32141/? A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   native: #10 pc 0025237b  /data/app/edu.cias.rit.rocreadar-1/lib/arm/libarchitect.so (Java_com_wikitude_architect_Gameplay_createNative+74)
11-23 16:32:28.615  32141-32141/? A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   native: #11 pc 002c742f  /data/app/edu.cias.rit.rocreadar-1/oat/arm/base.odex (Java_com_wikitude_architect_Gameplay_createNative__+74)
11-23 16:32:28.615  32141-32141/? A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   at edu.cias.rit.rocreadar.AbstractArchitectCamActivity.onCreate(unavailable:-1)
11-23 16:32:28.615  32141-32141/? A/art﹕ art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   at edu.cias.rit.rocreadar.MainActivity.onCreate(unavailable:-1)
11-23 16:32:28.718      194-194/? A/DEBUG﹕ pid: 32141, tid: 32141, name: s.rit.rocreadar  >>> edu.cias.rit.rocreadar <<<
11-23 16:32:28.746      194-194/? A/DEBUG﹕ #10 pc 0025237b  /data/app/edu.cias.rit.rocreadar-1/lib/arm/libarchitect.so (Java_com_wikitude_architect_Gameplay_createNative+74)
11-23 16:32:28.746      194-194/? A/DEBUG﹕ #11 pc 0070642f  /data/app/edu.cias.rit.rocreadar-1/oat/arm/base.odex (offset 0x43f000)
11-23 16:32:29.034    792-32172/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Force finishing activity edu.cias.rit.rocreadar/.MainActivity
11-23 16:32:29.046      792-954/? I/WindowState﹕ WIN DEATH: Window{a8674fb u0 edu.cias.rit.rocreadar/edu.cias.rit.rocreadar.SplashScreen}
11-23 16:32:29.075     792-1700/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Process edu.cias.rit.rocreadar (pid 32141) has died
```

Comment: Solved it following this github documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Using the usage.txt file from the outputs folder and -keep rules in the proguard-rules.pro file. This solved the problem for me. Follow these instructions from this github documentation: https://github.com/futurice/android-best-practices

Adding the part of the documentation here, in case the documentation becomes obsolete:

Proguard configuration

ProGuard is normally used on Android projects to shrink and obfuscate the packaged code.

Whether you are using ProGuard or not depends on your project configuration. Usually you would configure gradle to use ProGuard when building a release apk.

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
    }
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

In order to determine which code has to be preserved and which code can be discarded or obfuscated, you have to specify one or more entry points to your code. These entry points are typically classes with main methods, applets, midlets, activities, etc. Android framework uses a default configuration which can be found from SDK_HOME/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt. Using the above configuration, custom project-specific ProGuard rules, as defined in my-project/app/proguard-rules.pro, will be appended to the default configuration.

A common problem related to ProGuard is to see the application crashing on startup with ClassNotFoundException or NoSuchFieldException or similar, even though the build command (i.e. assembleRelease) succeeded without warnings. This means one out of two things:

ProGuard has removed the class, enum, method, field or annotation, considering it's not required.
ProGuard has obfuscated (renamed) the class, enum or field name, but it's being used indirectly by its original name, i.e. through Java reflection.
Check app/build/outputs/proguard/release/usage.txt to see if the object in question has been removed. Check app/build/outputs/proguard/release/mapping.txt to see if the object in question has been obfuscated.

In order to prevent ProGuard from stripping away needed classes or class members, add a keep options to your ProGuard config:

-keep class com.futurice.project.MyClass { *; }
To prevent ProGuard from obfuscating classes or class members, add a keepnames:

-keepnames class com.futurice.project.MyClass { *; }
Check this template's ProGuard config for some examples. Read more at Proguard for examples.

Early on in your project, make a release build to check whether ProGuard rules are correctly keeping whatever is important. Also whenever you include new libraries, make a release build and test the apk on a device. Don't wait until your app is finally version "1.0" to make a release build, you might get several unpleasant surprises and a short time to fix them.

Tip. Save the mapping.txt file for every release that you publish to your users. By retaining a copy of the mapping.txt file for each release build, you ensure that you can debug a problem if a user encounters a bug and submits an obfuscated stack trace.

DexGuard. If you need hard-core tools for optimizing, and specially obfuscating release code, consider DexGuard, a commercial software made by the same team that built ProGuard. It can also easily split Dex files to solve the 65k methods limitation.